# How to bulid a new neural network or use a learned one for prediction when some variables are missing

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references, missing-data

Let's say I have a neural network for weather forecasting. The network uses temperature, wind speed and humidity as its inputs. However, I only have temperature and wind speed data available, so I can't get a prediction with this network. Is there a way to build a new network that can handle variable input size? That is, I need to get a prediction with only 2/3 inputs.

Please link papers if possible.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a network that has already been trained on a dataset containing temp, wind, and humidity. I don't understand the situation with the new dataset. Is it the case that: 1) All points contain only temp and wind? or 2) Each point may contain some missing variables, but not always? Do you have access to the dataset used to train the original network?

Comment: It's a hypothetical situation I used to simplify the problem. In reality I have an over 100 features dataset and a neural network already trained. The problem is that I have some new input data to predict that could have some missing values (one point may have 3 missing, the next 5, the next none, etc...) . Retraining a new model would not be a problem, since I have the original datasets.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need a network with 'variable input size'. You should just adjust your normalisation technique.

If your input is limited to `[0,1]`. Make sure to set 0 as 'no data available' and the rest of the range (e.g. `[0.01-1]`) for when there IS data avalaible.

Then train your network with a wide range of test cases, and when data is missing in a test case: set the input value of that var to 0. **You can train your neural network to work with a missing var.**

---

What you could do:

Determine the correlation between temperature, wind speed and humidity. If one of the three is missing, *estimate* the missing variable with the two present variables. You could use a neural network for that as well.

But still, backpropagation is some kind of magic. Just try to feed some data with missing variables and see how it performs.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have enough cases with data missing in training and I don't want to invent data. Also I'm worried that without enough training samples of this kind the networtk will make the assumption that 0 is almost the same as 0.001, which is not correct.

Comment: Hmm, I understand. That's a tough problem. I've edited my answer a little, but I have no further ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I found a paper with an interesting solution:

[Modeling Missing Data in Clinical Time Series with RNNs](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/proceedings/papers/v56/Lipton16.pdf)
: Models missing values as a feature, augmenting inputs with a binary variable that indicates wether an input has been inputed or not.